# How to add an element at the beginning of a JsonArray?

Tags: java, json, gson

Given a `JsonArray`, how can I insert an element at the beginning?

According to [the docs](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html), it doesn't have an `add(int, JsonElement)` overload (like an `ArrayList` would), and the `set(int, JsonElement)` method replaces the element at that index.

Comment: IMO, you can try the following steps: element1=get(0);, set(0,element_new);, add(element1);

Comment: prepending an element will imply that you shift all the elements in the array by one (unless you don't care that the first element can be added at the end). If you're working with several thousands of entry, is it really what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a new Array, adding your wanted element first and than add the existing array with [addAll](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonArray.html#addAll%28com.google.gson.JsonArray%29)

Comment: Wouldn't that end up making a full copy of the existing array's elements? That would be concerning as I'm working with several thousands of entries every second.